# 550 The address is not valid

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have a problem in CodeIgniter, sending a validation email:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 The address
>   is not valid.
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1553

Comment: i presume you are not on `localhost` and has a valid smtp server config?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error means your mail server requires SMTP authentication to send emails. You may have two options, one is to change to another SMTP server that does not require authentication.

The other option will be to put the credentials in your config. Please check [this page](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html), and try with the `smtp_user/smtp_pass` settings.

If you post your config settings and the use case, I'll be able to provide you with more details.

Comment: I use mydomain to send email

Comment: @Ahmad, Can you share your config settings?.There are several options related to what you put there, that may cause this behavior.

Comment: $config['protocol'] = 'mail';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.cam-corp.com';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'admin@cam-corp.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = '***';
        $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
        $config['wordwarp'] = 'TRUE';
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
        $config['priority'] = '3';
        
        $this->load->library('email', $config);

Comment: When you are using the mail protocol, CI does a call using the mail or sendmail. So check if ini_get("safe_mode") returns true. if it does, it means that is using the mail function, if returns false it means that´s using sendmail. In both cases I will recommend to try in a sepparate php / command line . You´ll see how CI does this in the file   located at /system/library/Email.php in your CI proyect. Check the line 1539 and 1553 to reproduce the example. Let me know if you have any progress.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, "550 The address is not valid." means that the mail server cannot accept your email because it cannot find the mailbox "admin@cam-corp.com". Are you sure that you have configured your mailserver properly?